# No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

Tags: kinect, openni, ubuntu, freenect, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Someone please help.  I've tried every solution I can fin on the web.  I'm running ubuntu 14.04 I have a Kinect and I'd like it to work with ROS.  Nothing I've tried has worked.  Can anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243153/no-devices-connected....-waiting-for-devices-to-be-connected/) by [swilker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25514/swilker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-09-05

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-05**:
This has been asked and answered lots of times on this forum, and there are lots of different possible problems. Without the specifics of what hardware you have, how it's connected, and the exact commands and errors we can't help you.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-05**:
Please read the [support page](http://wiki.ros.org/Support) for guidelines on how to ask good questions.

**Comment by [swilker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25514/swilker/) on 2016-09-06**:
Running on Nuc-I7 Ubuntu14.04 with ROS usb connector, setup using: *sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-freenect-stack* Old-school Kinect works fine, Asus-XTion and prime sense get's error: no devices connected... I've worked through every post I could find on the topic, stuck, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think we have this figured out.  I will post what we did to make it work once I've made sure it's correct.  Thanks to everyone that has sent suggestions.

---

Originally posted by [swilker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25514/swilker/) with karma: 51 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0